# Validity of Proof $\zeta(\overline{s}) = \overline{\zeta(s)}$ for $\Re(s)>0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, riemann-zeta

We want to show the Riemann zeta function's magnitude is mirrored above and below the real axis, but that it's argument (phase) is inverted:

$$ \zeta(\overline{s}) = \overline{\zeta(s)} $$

We will restrict ourselves to $\sigma>0$ where $s=\sigma+it$.

**Question: is the proof correct?**

---

For the simplest case, we'll use $\zeta(s)=\sum 1/n^s$, valid for $\sigma>1$.

We consider each term in the series:

$$n^{-\overline{s}}=e^{-\overline{s}\ln(n)}=\overline{e^{-sln(n)}}=\overline{n^{-s}}$$

The magnitudes at $s$ and $\overline{s}$ are easy to equate.

$$|n^{-\overline{s}}|=|\overline{n^{-s}}|$$

This means $\zeta(\overline{s})$ is the complex conjugate of $\zeta(s)$. So, although the magnitude of $\zeta(s)$ is mirrored above and below the real axis, the sign of the imaginary part is inverted.

---

For the extended case, we'll use the series valid for $\sigma>0$

$$\zeta(s)=\frac{1}{1-2^{1-s}}\cdot\eta(s)$$

where eta $\eta(s)$ is the alternating zeta function.

Here we can immediately say:

$$\eta(\overline{s})=\overline{\eta(s)}$$

because it is the same as $\sum 1/n^s$ but with alternating signs.

Then we look at the other factor:

$$(1-2^{1-\overline{s}})^{-1} = \overline{\left(1-2^{1-s}\right)^{-1}}$$

because $1/\overline{z}=\overline{1/z}$ which can be shown using polar representations.

Therefore we have:

$$\begin{align} \zeta(\overline{s}) &= ({1-2^{1-\overline{s}})^{-1}}\cdot\eta(\overline{s})\\ \\ &=\overline{(1-2^{1-s})^{-1}}\; \cdot \; \overline{\eta(s)} \\ \\ &= \overline{\zeta(s)} \end{align}$$

Giving us the same conclusions that the magnitude is mirrored in the real axis, but the phase is inverted.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3266517/the-riemann-zeta-function-for-complex-conjugates) for a general argument.

Comment: Since $\overline{\zeta\left(\overline{z}\right)}$ and $\zeta(z)$ are simultaneously analytic, doesn't it follow for the whole domain of analyticity once you've proved it on a set with a limit point?

Comment: hi @DietrichBurde - thanks for the link I will explore more general arguments. Is the simple argument above correct (for teaching students who aren't trained to a high level as required by the more general arguments) ?

Comment: I'd really appreciate if someone could confirm if the main argument is correct.